# WSO2 API Manager: Restrict API Call based on Few Constraints

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I should use few constraints for our APIs **per user**. for example (after validation of token) checking IP address, checking specific parameter in query string and other custom constraints which maybe required to fetch data from data base . what is the suitable solution to implement this constraint in API call time? using custom mediator in outflow? using scope feature? using throttling policy or other.
thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to write a custom handler which allows you to customise as your requirement. This will help you to check all your extra constraints easily. Please refer this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Writing+Custom+Handlers) for more details.

And also you may be able to achieve this using a custom mediation flow too. But that depends on how granular you need to check the constraint. If checking does not involve a complex logic, then simple mediation flow would help you. Please refer this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I need a mechanism that provide configurable solution in run time and apply constraints per user not per API. can I have configurable custom handler? (I think no).

Comment: I think the best approach is the custom handler in which you have to check the constraints against the user. But if you can check the constraints against the roles solution would be much easier, because it is easier to check against roles than individual users. After the token validation, you will be able to fetch the user details from the message context from your custom handler. The custom handler should be engaged after the token validation handler.

Comment: I'm agree. as a result, the ability to configuration can be satisfied in data base side. thank you dear Geeth.